# Why large arrays do run time error while vectors don't?

Tags: c++

I have declare array with large size 10^5 in local function which gave me run time error, but when I took vector instead of an array the code was successful.
so why do vector does not gave error while array did??

Comment: Provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: A code sample would help! But if you declare the array as a local variable then you will run out of stack space. However a vector will allocate most of its memory on the heap and you will be fine.

Comment: This site if called Stack Overflow. And this is exactly the error you are experiencing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here this explains the difference between local variables (stack) and dynamically allocated memory (which std::vector uses)
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-vs-heap-memory-allocation/

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you provide the code snippet. But I can assume that you are create your array on the stack wich has size limit(usually up to few MB or even less than 1 MB).
Vector on the other hand allocate memory on the heap wich is usually much more than size of the stack.
So because heap size is sufficient to contain 10^5 byte you don't have an error when using vector. And because stack size is not enough to contain 10^5 byte you get a runtime error when using array.